# Using setTimeout correctly

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to make it so that it document.write() 9, then pause 1 second, writes 8, then pause 1 second, write 7, then pause 1 second, and so on and so forth until it hits 0. But right now it just prints the entire thing out at once. What am I doing wrong?

```
var delay = function(){
setTimeout(delay, 1000); // check again in a second
}

var count = 10;
while (count > 0) {
count--;
delay();
document.write(count);
}
```

9876543210

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

- Calling `setTimeout` only queues up a function to execute once the timeout expires - it doesn't pause the main thread.
- `document.write` is document.wrong, usually - if the document has already been parsed, it will be replaced with the new HTML string. Use proper DOM methods instead.

You could `await` promises every second and append `span`s:

```js
const delay = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
(async () => {
  let count = 10;
  while (count > 0) {
    await delay();
    count--;
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = count;
  }
})();
```

You could also (synchronously) set timeouts for each iteration:

```js
for (let count = 9; count >= 0; count--) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = count;
  }, (10 - count) * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is asynchronous, it does not pause execution.

```
var count = 10;
var delay = function(){
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
    document.write(count);
    setTimeout(delay, 1000); // check again in a second
  }
}
delay();
```

This could work, but I don't think document.write works after page finished loading. Meaning you cannot call it in a timeout callback.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `setInterval` and `console.log`

```
var count = 9;

var timer = setInterval(delay, 1000);

function delay() {
  console.log(count--);
  if(count<0)
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```